# I have trouble about try to open bmp file from axapta 2009

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, bmp, dynamics-ax-2009

We are using dynamics axapta 2009. when i try to open bmp file from dynamics axapta 2009 in windows 10 , I get error. But when i try to open in windows 7 or other operating systems, It works.

Do you guys have any idea about it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: It's not code, it standart dynamics ax feature. Please see the new pic from the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to associate a bmp file with the default program.

Type default program in the search bar.

[image]

[image]

Another possibility:
To associate a specific file format to a specific program, right-click on a file of the type in question and choose Open With, and then select Choose default program. You'll see a dialog box that lists all the applications installed on the computer that can open that particular file format. Choose the application you want to associate with the file, and then click OK.